# Is there a more elegant way of executing TimerTasks on JavaFX Application thread than nested anonymous Runnable?

Tags: java, timer, javafx, timertask, anonymous-inner-class

Let's say I have a custom [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) doing stuff.

So normally a timer task would look something like this:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do work...
    }
}
```

And I schedule it for a continuous repeating cycle via a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to execute every 10 seconds.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
myTimer.schedule(myTask,0,10000);
```

Under normal conditions this works just fine, but since I perform some GUI update operations in this task I have to call the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) from the JavaFX application thread.

In essence this means that I have to call the [`Platform.runLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) on the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) (`MyTimerTask`) when I want to run it.

But since I don't explicitly call the `run()` on the task since I put it on the TaskQueue via [`Timer.schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29), I have to resort to changing `MyTimerTask` to something like this:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Do work...
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Which feels like a very crude way to do this.

**So I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?**

Comment: This is pretty similar (almost a duplicate) to: [JavaFX periodic background task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task)

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX has the animation package that can also be used for updating the UI at regular intervals.

Take a look at the class [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) :

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10),
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
                 // do stuff
            }
        }
));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

The timeline will be executed automatically in the JavaFX thread.